# Database table model advice

Tags: database

I am making a Django web app and need help designing the a table within the DB.

I am to insert into the table an employee with a specific employee ID. Lets say there are three employees with the IDs (15039, 98443, 29234). Would the employee ID be the primary key or do I have to make some arbitrary column starting from 1 the primary id with employee id as a standalone column?

In a sense what I am i asking is if the 15039, 98443, and 29234 employees were inserted into the table with empl ID being primary key which order would the DMBS order them?

Comment: If the employee ***never***, ever, under no circumstance changes, then yes you should use them as the PK (but you need to be really, really sure about that). As for the second question: rows in a relational database don't have an order. The result of a query can be ordered. Picture a table as a basket with balls in it. They don't have "an order" either.

Comment: Rows have an order in the database, in the sense that the clustered index doesn't take extra space since it is how the table tree is ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify which database you will use, but most likely the primary key will be the clustered index, in which case the database will order the rows by that id.

Many argue you should always create an auto-increment artifical primary key, and that usually saves you a lot of pain in the long run.

However, if you know the value will always be unique and you won't ever need to change the value, you can opt to use it as the `PK` for the table.